# CGImageCreateWithImageInRect not cropping at correct position

Tags: ios, crop

I have a scenario in my app where I take a screenshot of the video using

```
[myMovieController requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:@[@(myMovieController.currentPlaybackTime)] timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
```

which just works fine. Then I have to crop the image with touched location on the video. I have added gesture recognizer of `myMovieController`. I get the touch location from the gesture Recognizer.

then I use following code to take the screen shot

```
CGRect cropRect = tapCircleView.frame;
cropRect = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x * image.scale,
                      touchPoint.y * image.scale,
                      cropRect.size.width * image.scale,
                      cropRect.size.height * image.scale);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], cropRect) ;
UIImage* cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
[self showImage:cropped];
```

where cropRect width and height is 150.

But crop result is not with correct x and y. And also resulting image is very pixilated.
I have tried every solution but it's not working.
What is it that I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The image size which captures screenshot is not same as device size on which application is running. 
So instead of using same image, change size of image using following code :

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,    [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( rect.size );
[image drawInRect:rect];
UIImage *picture1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture1);
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

And now just use this image wherever you want !!

Cheers.